# Variable background in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have profiles in my **Wordpress** website, every profile has its own image
I want to use that image as background of that current page too, Is it possible to use a *Class* in CSS which contains the image link as a *Value* of a new line of CSS?

```
.panel {
   background: "class(col-sm-4)";
}
```

Comment: Essentially **NO**.

Comment: Take a look at using inline styling for this

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly no way to accomplish this by default in Wordpress using only CSS. The background property only accepts specific arguments, and implementing variables as values is not possible without more advanced techniques than you get with out-of-the-box CSS.

Check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) for a full explanation of the background property and its accepted arguments.

However, since you are using Wordpress, you probably have the ability to insert Javascript/jQuery code into your site or page that would easily achieve the same effect.

If you update your question to give an example of your page content, we can make recommendations about how to accomplish the look you're targeting.

Comment: You are right buddy
I dont want to add jscript into my wordpress so I'm thinking to find another way, like using ID3 Tags of my audio files and costumize MediaElement.js with css. 
If you want you can check [This](https://devoiders.com/music/the-fingerprint-ep). out.

Thanks for your help